# WPF XAML Image.Source Binding supported Types

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

I have xaml like this:

```
<Image Source="{Binding MyImage}" />
```

**Where is the best documentation to which types the Source property by default (without separate converter) can bind to?**

bonus:

**Are there differences in .NET versions?**

*I wan't to bind in XAML to a viewmodel. So please no codebind like "Image.Source = ...;".*

**What i discovered so far:**

common sense answer:

- any class derived from ImageSource

MSDN documentation is mostly useless:

[MSDN Image Control](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.image(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Source Property: Gets or sets the ImageSource for the image.

[MSDN Image.Source Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.image.source(v=vs.110).aspx)

> XAML Values 
>      imageUri
>      System.String
>      A URI of the image file

The most usefull answer i found is in the .net source [ImageSourceConverter.cs](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationCore/Core/CSharp/System/Windows/Media/ImageSourceConverter.cs):

- string (Uri-like path)
- byte[]
- Stream
- Uri

Comment: You've already listed all types that the property can be bound to without a binding converter: `ImageSource`, and `string`, `Uri`, `Stream` and `byte[]` by built-in type conversion (by the ImageSourceConverter class). For any other source type, you'll need a binding converter.

Comment: Where is the documentation for this?
even here is nothing userfull: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imagesourceconverter(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Although WPF is extremely well documented (IMO), there are still gaps. But there's also the *Reference Source* that you've already found. Refer to that.

Answer (score 0):

The idea of the ImageSourceConverter is correct. A possible way is to implement your own Converter to support different types as source. To do this, we have to write a Converter which is converting different types into an object of type ImageSource. Here is a first approach:

```
[ValueConversion(typeof(object), typeof(ImageSource))]
public class CustomImageConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        ImageSource returnSource = null;

        if (value != null)
        {
            if (value is byte[])
            {
                //Your implementation of byte[] to ImageSource
                returnSource = ...;
            }
            else if (value is Stream)
            {
                //Your implementation of Stream to ImageSource
                returnSource = ...;
            } 
            ...          
        }
        return returnSource;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
}
```

By using an instance of this Converter, you are able to pass different source types as object to your Image:

```
<Image Source="{Binding MyImage, Converter={StaticResource MyCustomImageConverter}}"/>
```